# Java Web Service client with keystore

Tags: java, jax-ws, keystore

Maybe I can find some helpe here.
I need to access web service but first I need to authenticate my client using keystore. I cant use spring. 
In spring-ws.xml such configuration works for clients of my colleagues:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.support.CryptoFactoryBean" id="clientCrypto">
    <property name="configuration">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider">org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin</prop>
            <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">jks</prop>
            <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">${esb.keystore.password}</prop>
            <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias">${esb.keystore.user}</prop>
            <prop key="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">src\main\resources\${esb.keystore.location}</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My client is like this:

```
PortalCustomerService service = new PortalCustomerService();
PortalCustomerPortType port = service.getSomethingHttpPort();

BindingProvider bindingProvider = (BindingProvider) port;
Binding binding = bindingProvider.getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
handlerList.add(new MyHandler());
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);

//calling webmethod
MyResponse response = port.checkClients(getRequest());
```

and MyHandler has a method handleMessage  like this:

```
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
        // I think I need to add something here but I dont know what 
    } else {}

    return true;
}
```

I have private key: myportal.key, public key: portal.cer .
 Without authentication I got:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
```

Comment: That is a really bad question, Sorry :(

Comment: how can I improve this? :)

Comment: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keystore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
wont help :(

Comment: This won't fix. You need to start with understanding what is a keystore and how it works. In the current state there is a lot of explaining to be done and no one would attempt to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You may get some help by following

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
```

If the key is self-signed, so you may need to set the `TrustStore` properties too.